# "`ref` is not a prop" warning testing React components with forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I have a React component implemented with forwardRef:

```
const Checkbox = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
   ...
   return(
      <input ref={ref}
        ...
      />
   )
}
```

Then in unit tests, using jest(v29.3.1) + testing-library/react(v13.4.0), I get the following warning:

```
  console.error
    Warning: [object Object]: `ref` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop. (https://reactjs.org/link/special-props)

      139 |     const ref = createRef();
      140 |
    > 141 |     render(<Checkbox name="test" label="Checkbox label" ref={ref} />);
```

Seems to be like testing-library is not updated with forwardRef functionality...

How is this warning removed?

Answer (score 0):

One way to remove this warning is by executing tests using the `--silent` flag